# js css slider tutorial issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been trying my hand at a js slider tutorial and have been trying to get the slider to appear without having to click on one of the links (paris and milan etc).

So page opens, there's the slider.

I've tried having the div of the slider thumb container on the page without having

```
<ul id="fp_galleryList" class="fp_galleryList">
    <li>Paris</li>
    <li>New York</li>
</ul>
```

but it just shows up blank.

I'd really appreciate a nudge in the right direction.

Here's the tutorial for reference:[link](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/10/07/slider-gallery/comment-page-9/#comments)

Jsfiddle     [@pete fixed the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/vkqhscuL/8/)

I'm sorry my fiddle doesn't work but my code is there. (First time using Jsfiddle and Stackoverflow so please be nice ;))

```
<div id="fp_gallery" class="fp_gallery">

    <ul id="fp_galleryList" class="fp_galleryList">
        <li>Paris</li>
        <li>New York</li>
    </ul>

    <div id="fp_thumbContainer">
        <div id="fp_thumbScroller">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="content">
                    <div>
                        <a href="#"><img src="images/album1/thumbs/1.jpg" alt="images/album1/1.jpg" class="thumb" /></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="content">
                    <div>
                        <a href="#"><img src="images/album1/thumbs/2.jpg" alt="images/album1/2.jpg" class="thumb" /></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="content">
                    <div>
                        <a href="#"><img src="images/album1/thumbs/3.jpg" alt="images/album1/3.jpg" class="thumb" /></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="content">
                    <div>
                        <a href="#"><img src="images/album1/thumbs/1.jpg" alt="images/album1/1.jpg" class="thumb" /></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="content">
                    <div>
                        <a href="#"><img src="images/album1/thumbs/2.jpg" alt="images/album1/2.jpg" class="thumb" /></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="content">
                    <div>
                        <a href="#"><img src="images/album1/thumbs/3.jpg" alt="images/album1/3.jpg" class="thumb" /></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="content">
                    <div>
                        <a href="#"><img src="images/album1/thumbs/1.jpg" alt="images/album1/1.jpg" class="thumb" /></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="content">
                    <div>
                        <a href="#"><img src="images/album1/thumbs/2.jpg" alt="images/album1/2.jpg" class="thumb" /></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="content">
                    <div>
                        <a href="#"><img src="images/album1/thumbs/3.jpg" alt="images/album1/3.jpg" class="thumb" /></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="content">
                    <div>
                        <a href="#"><img src="images/album1/thumbs/1.jpg" alt="images/album1/1.jpg" class="thumb" /></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="content">
                    <div>
                        <a href="#"><img src="images/album1/thumbs/2.jpg" alt="images/album1/2.jpg" class="thumb" /></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="content">
                    <div>
                        <a href="#"><img src="images/album1/thumbs/3.jpg" alt="images/album1/3.jpg" class="thumb" /></a>
                    </div>
                </div>



            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>

<div id="fp_scrollWrapper" class="fp_scrollWrapper">
    <span id="fp_prev_thumb" class="fp_prev_thumb"></span>
    <div id="slider" class="slider"></div>
    <span id="fp_next_thumb" class="fp_next_thumb"></span>
</div>

<div id="fp_overlay" class="fp_overlay"></div>
<div id="fp_loading" class="fp_loading"></div>
<div id="fp_next" class="fp_next"></div>
<div id="fp_prev" class="fp_prev"></div>
<div id="fp_close" class="fp_close">Close preview</div>


<!--  JAVASCRIPT -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
```

Comment: Your fiddle looks screwed up. You shouldn't add `<script>` tags inside the HTML.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Will remove it and update. Thank you :)

Comment: @PraveenKumar I removed it but it still looks messed up. Did I paste my code in wrong?

Comment: Yes... You need to include jQuery and other resources in the resources tab on the left.

Comment: @PraveenKumar ok I'll figure out what I need and try get the urls

Comment: @PraveenKumar I've added the Jquery and easing.js to the resource panel but still no change. Any idea why? http://jsfiddle.net/TaliZorah/vkqhscuL/7/ Sorry added this too jquery-ui.min.js still no change though

Comment: Fixed your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/vkqhscuL/8/

Comment: @Pete Thank you so much! For future reference what was I missing/doing wrong?

Comment: you added jquery twice - once in the external resources and once in the frameworks and extensions and you included the closing script tag in the js part of the code

Comment: @Pete I see...Sorry silly mistake.

Comment: I've tried removing this <div id="fp_gallery" class="fp_gallery">
   

   <ul id="fp_galleryList" class="fp_galleryList">
    <li>Paris</li>
    <li>New York</li>
   </ul> and this var gallery_idx=-1; with no luck. I've also tried setting the idx to 1 but no luck either. Any thoughts?